# What do you say on a person's 120th birthday?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, age

Normally, most people wish someone "Ad meah ve'esrim" ([May you live] to a hundred and twenty). What do you say on a person's hundred and twentieth birthday.

I have seen the answers about why 120 connected to Moshe Rabbeinu and that this is considered the maximum age (even though Aharon lived to 123, and Miriam to (about) 133. I have also seen the references to Parshas Noach, even though there are meforshim who say the reference is to the number of years until the mabul and not the maximum age that humanity would start decreasing towards.

Note that I first heard this as a joke, but serious answers are being sought here.

The original answer that I heard was for the joke and not serious ("Have a nice day") so it would not really be appropriate for this question.

Comment: -It looks like it might not be regarded as a question- Since it is only "Normally, you wish someone *Ad meah ve'esrim*", just pick another wish.

More importantly, where did this wish come from ? My Ra"m once told me that it has no profound source and we should rather wish people *Ad meah ve'esrim ve'yoter* (or somethnig like that)

[Might be better to ask, Why do people assume you may only live up till 120]

Comment: @Zeev I have already seen the answer that it is tied to Moshe Rabbeinu and that people are not considered to be ablye to outdo him. Even thogh Aharon lived to 123 and Miriam to approximately 193, the maximum age for modern people is normally considered to match Moshe Rabbeinu.

Comment: Until 180 - the age of the Avos and I sometimes hear it used anyway.

Comment: Where did you learn that Miriam lived to 193? I always heard ~125.

Comment: @Ypnypn Miriam died the same year that Moshe and Aharon died. Now that I look at it, the 9 was a typo and should have bee a 3. I have seen references that she was 5, 7, or 13 when Moshe was born. The 13 is based on people who say she was Puah, which means that she was at least bas mitzvah when she was already a midwife. Thanks for pointing out my typo.

Comment: In modern times, this question has had practical relevance for a Mrs. Jeanne Calment (1875-1997) of Arles, France.  AFAIK, she wasn't Jewish, though.

Answer (score 5):

According to Rabbi Shurkin in his *Meged Givas Olam*, some great rabbis he studied under were against the idea that one can only live to one hundred and twenty years.

He cited an incident where Reb Moshe Feinstein wouldn't fill out a certain life insurance policy when he realized it would only cover him till one hundred and twenty years.

Also, if I may add, our tradition tells us Chutzpis Hameturgaman was murdered the day before his one hundred and thirtieth birthday, so the one twenty idea seems to have no real basis.

So, in closing, wish them many more happy years of life.

Comment: I was told (by an insurance salesman) the life insurance policies originally cashed out at 100. As a result of people living longer, they are now written to cash out at 121.

Comment: I thought that Chutzpit (love that name) lived until 1**13**

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt It doesn't matter. Yehoyada' lived to 130 http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b24.htm#15 The only sad part is people knowing Midrashim about Chuztpis better than Tanakh...

Comment: @Double The Baalei Tosafos would probably not agree with that statement.

Comment: @user6591 I disagree?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I didn't realise that any of Chaza"l lived to that age group.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Frankly, we don't really have any reason to think any did or didn't. Not that it matters at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA Or that living until 120 is only for post-biblical people (if not, then you have the Avos) and Chutzpis would be a stronger proof.

Comment: @shmue what's post biblical? In the Torah we have Aharon well after the avot. After the Torah? After neviim? After Ketuvim? Why would the end of Ketuvim be a relevant start time?

Answer (score 2):

Given the plethora of blessings that one may give on someone's birthday, the answers to this question are innumerable.
So the answer is - any blessing except for Ad 120.